# The int column data length cannot be set, turn zero after saving in mysql,but varchar and datetime can set

Tags: mysql

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TYhUi.png)

How to resolve this problem?

Comment: `The data length cannot be set` what length you tried ?

Comment: any number in int range

Comment: What number did you try? More than 255 ?

Comment: no, i set 8,the int column length can't lager than 255 ?

Comment: Yes Thats why i asked whether you are trying to set more than 255

Comment: It doesn't work fine.when i set 8,turn zero after saving in mysql.

Comment: i think of it might be mysql setting problem

Comment: Interger datatypes length specification is deprecated.